# Possible shopping question: "Where can I get gear like this?"

Tags: discussion, scope

As I know Stack Exchange generally frowns on "shopping questions", I wanted to ask about this here on Meta before posting it on Main.

I own a piece of gear (a hat) and I would like to buy another one similar to it, but I have not been able to find one.  I would like to ask the community if anyone knows of a similar item currently on the market.

**Would such a question be acceptable?  Is there anything in particular that I should include or avoid?**

I would include a description and picture of the item I'm trying to replace.  I'm not really looking for general suggestions on what to buy, though if someone has experience with a similar product that would of course be useful.  It would be useful for answers suggesting a product to include information about where I could buy it, but price shopping is not the focus of my question.

Comment: Your best bet for this may be [chat] as you are right - that seems to be very much in the 'shopping question' space

Comment: What @RoryAlsop said ^

Answer (score 7):

If you were in search of a specific piece of equipment to solve a problem (i.e. does this <thing> exist? or something similar?), then it would probably make it good Q&A. But since you are essentially asking if anyone's seen a hat similar to yours, it's a tougher sell. Since you're really just looking for a place where you can buy something, perhaps in this case it is better brought to a chat room rather than becoming the canon of this Q&A.

But let's be careful about making this about "shopping recommendations." The [Let's go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) blog post was designed to keep a site from becoming an endless buying guide — countless users asking *"Which camera is best?"*

But that cautionary advice has often been completely overblown, and now the mere mention of *"I need to purchase"* can take a perfectly legitimate question and get it closed. And that is a shame.

Gear talk is usually the mainstay of any half-way *decent* outdoors site. Let's not lose sight of that. I wish there was more of it on this site.