# "Where can I buy" vs. "Price shopping"

Tags: discussion

Referring to:  [Where can I buy bear banger launcher and ammunition and have them shipped to US?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/where-can-i-buy-bear-banger-launcher-and-ammunition-and-have-them-shipped-to-us).

This question is not price shopping assistance.  It is, at the core, a question of how to get something in the U.S.  There are multiple examples of similar "where can I find" questions on the site.

Examples:
[Where can I find an iodine crystal water purification product?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1706/where-can-i-find-an-iodine-crystal-water-purification-product)
[Where can I find good topographical maps of Peru?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13170/where-can-i-find-good-topographical-maps-of-peru)
[Where to get replacement parts for a Ugly Stik GX2](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13577/where-to-get-replacment-parts-for-a-ugly-stik-gx2)
[Refillable camping stoves for use in the UK](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/refillable-camping-stoves-for-use-in-the-uk)
[Where can I get long but light bottoms for water?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8352/where-can-i-get-long-but-light-bottoms-for-water)
[Where to buy ethanol in Canada?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5575/where-to-buy-ethanol-in-canada)

Other shopping questions:
[What Rope to purchase?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/what-rope-to-purchase/4916)
  [Why shouldn't I buy an ultra light tent?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5966/why-shouldnt-i-buy-an-ultra-light-tent)
The list goes on...

Price shopping means price shopping, not anything that can be shoe-horned into the broader category of shopping.

"Sourcing hard to find gear" *may* be a topic the community wants to ban.  If so let's start that meta and have that discussion.

I suggest before anyone does they read Robert's answer to basically that exact question: https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/a/588/127  --  ***"Gear talk is usually the mainstay of any half-way decent outdoors site. Let's not lose sight of that. I wish there was more of it on this site."***  (emphasis mine)

Also consider in our general outlook for flagging - [Should we be more critical of questions (and closing many more than we do) to maintain quality of site?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/629/should-we-be-more-critical-of-questions-and-closing-many-more-than-we-do-to-ma)

Comment: I think, rightly or wrongly, asking where to source items is perfectly fine - even though sometimes the answers maybe as time limited as an actual price on a website (eg, websites may not sell them anymore, item has been updated to a new model etc). Perhaps in this case it would be better to supply multiple sources in an answer - or if you DO post an answer and notice that the product has changed, revisit it and maybe update it? - you see this on SO when code is deprecated or a framework changes.

Comment: Take it there's not way to re-word the "price shopping" close reason? It does seem to confuse many people

Comment: @Liam -- I'm not sure to what extent we can get that, but if we had better wording, I'd be happy to kick it up the line to the larger SO.

Comment: Knocked something up, sure it's far from perfect so please amend if you want

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. The whole issue is confusing, especially because it's different than some of the other sites. I agree that re-wording that reason would be very helpful, both to users and reviewers. Sorry I don't have a good suggestion, just wanted to say I appreciate seeing the topic raised!

Comment: @Sue -- Thank you.  I have seen it said a number of times that TGO is unlike typical SO both in culture and rules.

Comment: I'm curious about [Are there any low sodium meals?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/980/), a post you made wiki in March, 2013. It asks "if"  there are low-sodium dinners, which seems on-topic, but also for a price range, which might fall into the close reason?  Some answers list brands, which I think is okay, but also prices, which I imagine are obsolete by now. It's a wiki post, so does that mean it's still on-topic? Should prices be edited out? It had a format edit yesterday, so people are still seeing it. Clarification would help me know what I can ask. Thank you!

Comment: @Sue I definitely think your comment above would be better served as a question on meta or as an experiment where you ask the question you want on the main site and see what happens. My take is a price range is reasonable requirement, so including prices to show it is within the range feels appropriate. Of course the price should always include a disclaimer of something along the lines of "currently the price is generally between X and Y which fits your budget of A and B." Just my opinion though. Bottom line though if you want more feedback you need to do more than ask in a comment.

Comment: The [link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) may not have been there when this was posted.

Answer (score 4):

The current text is a little vague and confusing. Currently it reads:

> Questions seeking price-shopping assistance are off-topic because they
>   tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and
>   the specific problem you're trying to solve.

For me the issue is the term *price-shopping*. People tend to read this as shopping advice. Regardless of whether it's for a product recommendation (which is **on** topic) or a price recommendation (which is **off** topic).

> Asking for advice on where is the cheapest place to obtain a product
>   or service is off-topic. They tend to become obsolete quickly.
>   Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're
>   trying to solve. If you want [advice on which product you may need for
>   a particular scenario](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/possible-shopping-question-where-can-i-get-gear-like-this), define what your requirements are for this
>   product carefully and highlight what functions you wish it to perform

I've knocked this up above. Please feedback any amendments. I think we need to keep it quite short and pithy, so please we don't want to over describe the problem. If anyone can shorten this I think it could be welcome?

Comment: I'll see about how (and if) we can get this changed in the coming days.